# Why is floated div being blocked from wrapping to container edge?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `<div>` elements floated left inside a `<div>` wrapper. When the screen narrows, the 3rd `<div>` should wrap around and position itself under the 1st `<div>`. What I'm experiencing, however, is that the 3rd `<div>` is wrapping only as far as the 2nd `<div>`, and I can't figure out why. Please check my CSS and point out where I'm going wrong.

```css
body {
  background: #d2e1ff;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
}
#step2 {
 min-width: 150px;
 max-width: 600px;
}
label {
  font-size: 80%;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 98%;
}
.element {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.element label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.column1 {
  width: 30%;
}
.column2 {
  width: 40%;
}
input#day,input#month {
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 2em;
}
input#day,input#month,input#year {
  color: #999999;
  width: 3em;
}
@media all and (max-width:400px){
 .element {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="step2">
  <div class="element column2">
    <label for="telephone">Telephone number</label>
    <input id="telephone" type="text" name="telephone">
  </div>
  <div class="element column2">
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <select id="gender" name="gender">
      <option value="">Select Gender</option>
      <option value="m">Male</option>
      <option value="f">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="element column1">
    <label for="day">Date of birth</label>
    <input id="day" type="text" name="day" value="dd">
    <input id="month" type="text" name="month" value="mm">
    <input id="year" type="text" name="year" value="yyyy">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is interesting behavior. You're right: it is reasonable to think that the third `div` should wrap all the way back and position itself under the first `div` in column 1.  That's how floats are supposed to work.

Here's a simple demo. Three boxes, floated left. Just like your layout. When you adjust screen width they wrap as expected.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ah2fvgtv/4/)

And this is what you're experiencing:

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ah2fvgtv/12/)

The **solution to the problem** is very simple:

> Add a `height` rule to each div.

```
.element {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    height: 50px; /* This solves the problem */
}
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ah2fvgtv/9/)

#### Here's what's happening...

It seems that the padding from the Telephone input field is making div box #1 slightly taller than the Gender box. This extra height is literally blocking div box #3 from shifting to the edge of the container.

*In this image, the Date of Birth box, which is floated left, is unable to wrap all the way to the container edge. The Telephone div is blocking it.*

[image]

If we give the telephone input a `padding: 0`, the height is reduced and the obstruction is removed:

```
input[type="text"] { padding: 0; }
```

[image]

*But who the hell wants text fields with no padding?*

There is a clean, simple and effective solution to this problem, and it doesn't involve removing the padding from form inputs: Add a height rule to the div class (as described above).

```
.element { height: 50px; }
```

[image]

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ah2fvgtv/9/)

**A second possible solution** is to give div #2 enough bottom margin to clear the height of div #1.

```
<div class="element column2" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
<!-- not necessarily recommending inline style; just for demo purposes -->
```

---

#### One side note...

**Collapsed Container**
Your parent container (`id="step2"`) isn't wrapping anything, because you've floated the child elements – which takes them out of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow) – but you didn't "notify the parent". So your container `div` has 0 height since it has no content.

To observe this behavior yourself, highlight the `div` with `id="step2"` in Chrome Dev Tools or add a border around it.

*In your code the top and bottom borders of parent container `id="step2"` are touching, because the box has no content and, therefore, no height.*

[image]

From a practical perspective, this means that many styles will be lost on this container (try adding a background color to `#step2`).

There are several ways to address this issue – known as **[clearfix methods](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)**. In this case I've used the `overflow` property. Add `overflow: auto` to the container `div`.

```
#step2 { overflow: auto; }
```

[image]

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ah2fvgtv/11/)

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Setting a negative position would drastically change the layout of the complete finished page as the column css styles are meant to control mainly just the width (i.e. I wouldn't want all items with 30% width to have a negative position - what if the first element was 30% width!?)

Comment: Yeah, you can disregard that. It was just a hack option in case you needed a blunt fix. But I was going to remove it anyway when I had a complete answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, you've been most helpful, although I still don't understand why those css styles you pointed out would cause an issue with the floating! It's peculiar things like these that keep one awake throughout the night trying to fix it...

Comment: Yes, I'll probably spend some time later trying to figure out why those rules kill the normal float behavior. I'll update my answer when it's clear. But for now, we've identified the problem and you should be able to complete the project without this problem getting in the way.

Comment: So just played around some more and problem isn't quite solved - Setting a width (e.g. 61%) so that it's impossible to fit the 3rd div and either of the others (column2) on a single line will shift the 3rd div back inline to the left side. I would prefer to keep the width appropriate to the content, but the behaviour is still aligning to the left of the 2nd div. I can obviously work around the problem in various ways, but I'm still no closer to understanding the original problem xD

http://jsfiddle.net/4bjresdb/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86744/discussion-between-michael-b-and-trung-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

There's no `clear: left` rule on the third `<div>`. The layout only advances to the bottom of the second `<div>`, which is slightly shorter than the first. The third div floats left, but the first one is, like, in the way. So it doesn't go all the way out to the margin.

If you're interested in how floats work, see [Introduction to floats](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#introduction-to-floats).

> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its margin edge touches the containing block edge **or the margin edge of another float**.

(emphasis added)

Here I've added some background colors to visualize the problem. I've also added `clear: left` to a new `new-row` class.

```css
body {
  background: #d2e1ff;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
}
#step2 {
 min-width: 150px;
 max-width: 600px;
}
label {
  font-size: 80%;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 98%;
}
.element {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.element label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.column1 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lime;
}
.column2 {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.new-row {
  clear: left;
}
input#day,input#month {
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 2em;
}
input#day,input#month,input#year {
  color: #999999;
  width: 3em;
}
@media all and (max-width:400px){
 .element {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="step2">
  <div class="element column2">
    <label for="telephone">Telephone number</label>
    <input id="telephone" type="text" name="telephone">
  </div>
  <div class="element column2">
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <select id="gender" name="gender">
      <option value="">Select Gender</option>
      <option value="m">Male</option>
      <option value="f">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="element column1 new-row">
    <label for="day">Date of birth</label>
    <input id="day" type="text" name="day" value="dd">
    <input id="month" type="text" name="month" value="mm">
    <input id="year" type="text" name="year" value="yyyy">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All the `<div>` elements are floating left, so I would expect it to just wrap around to the beginning of the next line without needing to specifically identify and set a `clear` on a certain item that wraps around. Is there a more general solution? I guess what I don't understand is what's causing the 3rd element to shift from the left side?

Comment: Floating elements aren't laid out like inline flow. They don't, by default, wrap around to the beginning of the column. That's how they enable layouts like [this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/float2p.png), where the second paragraph continues just under the first one.

Comment: @Michael_B - That's exactly the behaviour I was expecting. So where am I going wrong and complicating things in my example? Is it because I'm not using a defined width in pixels rather than a %?

Comment: So I played around with pxiel widths and had no difference. It's quite peculiar that the 3rd div aligns itself to the left of the 2nd div after dropping off the line...

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. The issue is that because of `padding` on the `input` in the `telephone` div is pushing the height of that div to be taller than the `gender` div. As stated in the answer, you need to `clear: left` on the `year of birth` div.

Comment: @disinfor, I'm not sure that explains why box #3 doesn't wrap all the way to the edge, when there are large vertical margins (which you can see in the image in my answer)..

Comment: @disinfor, in addition, the `clear` property shifts box #3 to a second row permanently (as illustrated in this answer). The OP wants all the 3 boxes on one row, but to wrap to new rows on smaller screens, adhering to normal float behavior .

Comment: @Michael_B to answer your first question, is because you set the `margin` on *ALL* containers. That means that the first container, is still taller than container two.

Comment: @Michael_B Second question, welcome to the wonderful world of `@media` queries. The OP needs to set the `clear:left` on screens that are smaller than a certain pixel, e.g. `@media all and (max-width:768px) { css here }`

Comment: @disinfor, thanks for the clarification. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @disinfor, with regard to media queries, I think that's a bit of overkill. Adding some height to the div boxes or a little bottom margin to div #2 gets the job done for all screen sizes.

Comment: @Michael_B No, it's not overkill. What if the content of either of those `element` divs changes? Adding height won't fix that for screen sizes. You'll run into more issues. `@media` queries are the perfect job for this, and I would say recommended.

Comment: @disinfor, well, they are form controls, which is normally fixed content, but I get what you're saying. Note the OP is already using a media query, so I'm sure he understands what you're saying, as well.

Comment: you should also consider using `flex` layout, if it's supported in the browsers you're targeting